# change URL using javascript Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to change the URL in the address bar using javascript.
So if the user access the page using

> www.example.com/ajax/project8.html

Url should be changed automatically to

> www.examp.com/#cbp=ajax/project8.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a redirect page in jQuery/JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE**

So you want your site to redirect to another page when the url is `www.example.com/ajax/project.aspx?id=whatever` and `id=xxx` could be any id.

To achieve that you need a function that returns the query string parameter value `eg:id=whatever`

Then check if the current url needs to be redirected to another page. If this is the case then redirect to new url with same parameter value.

```
        /*
        function that returns a query string parameter value
        this function works with many parameters
        Eg: www.example.com/#cbp=ajax/project.aspx?myParam=hello&id=1283&otherParam=234
        to get the param value just give it the parameters name
        getQueryStringValue("id") returns : 1283
        getQueryStringValue("myParam") returns : "hello"
        */
        function getQueryStringValue( name ){
          name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
          var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
          var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
          var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
          if( results == null )
            return "";
          else
            return results[1];
        }

        //current url 
        var currentUrl = location.href;

        //check if current url contains www.example.com/ajax/project.aspx
        if (currentUrl.indexOf("www.example.com/ajax/project.aspx") != -1 ){

            //new url for redirection
            var newUrl = "www.example.com/#cbp=ajax/project.aspx?id=" + getQueryStringValue( "id" );

            //redirect to new page
            location.href = newUrl;


        }
```

Comment: project8.html is a page from bunch of other pages that i want to change the url for, sorry for the inconvenience but think of it as project.aspx?id=8

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you want.. ? Explain your problem more precisely please.. You want to change the url for many pages ?

Comment: yes, i want to redirect user from www.example.com/ajax/project.aspx?id=xxx to www. example.com/#cbp=ajax/project.aspx?id=xxx

Answer (score 5):

shouldn't be any harder than this:

```
window.location = "http://whatever.you.want.com"
```

Comment: i think the challenge is todo this without page refresh

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
if (window.location.href == 'www.example.com/ajax/project8.html') {
  window.location = 'www.examp.com/#cbp=ajax/project8.html';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can set all things like

```
window.location.href = "www.examp.com/#cbp=ajax/project8.html"
```

for more details how you will manage all url parameter then please see

[**JavaScript and jQuery url managment**](http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery%22)

Answer (score 1):

`window.location.href = "#cbp=ajax/project8.html";`

you can change the value written after # to any location , div id etc.
e.g

`window.location.href = "#myDivID";`

Comment: super like to this answer. I want exactly this

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/" />
```

Note: please put on header

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.location.assign("http://www.example.com")
</script>
```